# Alternatives to website publishing photos

Tags: iphone, ios, content-management-system

Im currently using worpress to publish/upload images and show them on an iphone application. So my question... What is the best and most reliable CMS to integrate with an iphone application, that feeds from an online resource? :)

Best Regards.

Comment: What is the transport used to fetch these images? What will happen to the photos, do you have to edit them? Etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create your own app (for your own usage) that transfers the images via ftp from your iPhone to your ftp space?

Comment: Im using a rss feed parser. How do i acomplish that Ade?, is there any tutorials or articles that i can read?

Comment: I'm guessing that you have an iPhone app that gets data from an rss feed from a wordpress site. You upload your images to the site using the wordpress admin section of your website but wonder if there's a better solution? I imagine that the wordpress app would be good? what problem are you having or wanting to overcome?

Comment: Yes and yes, im just wondering if there is a better solution. Thanks for the response.